# Using a for-each loop to search for strings in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

So I want to use for-each loops to search in my arraylist in order to find the capital of the country that's typed in, also the search isn't case sensitive. The arraylist name in my other class that is ElementsList. Below is the code from the Country() class that includes the capital:

```
import java.text.*;
/**
* Write a description of class Country here.
*
* @author (your name)
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
public class Country
{

private String nCountry;
private String Cont;
private int Area;
private double populationNum;
private double GDP;
private String Capital;

public Country (){
    nCountry = "Default";
}
public Country (String name, String continent, int area, double population,
double gdp, String capital){
    nCountry = name;
    Cont = continent;
    Area = area;
    populationNum = population;
    GDP = gdp;
    Capital = capital;

}
 public String getCountry(){
    return nCountry;
}
public String getCapital(){
    return Capital;
}
  public void setCountry(String name){
    nCountry = name;
}


public void setCapital(String capital){
    Capital = capital;
}    


}
```

The thing I'm having trouble with is creating the for-each loop to search for the capital of the country that is being used. It's not much but this is what I've got so far:

```
   public String searchForCapital(String countryName){

    Country cap = new Country();
    cap = null;
    for(Country c : ElementsList){
        if(c.getCountry().equals(countryName)){


   }
```

Comment: So what part are you specifically having trouble with?

Comment: Also, is that you're entire country class? I'm not actually seeing a getCountry() method anywhere there.

Comment: No its not the entire country class, here I'll put in the getcountry() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `for each` is right. here is the full function to search for capital,Note that you have to have `elementsList` array list of `Country` objects

```
public String searchForCapital(String countryName) {

    for (Country c : elementsList) {
        if (c.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase(countryName)) {
            return c.getCapital();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```